# Discord Py ORDER BY - wrong order

Tags: python, discord.py, mysql-python

```py
@commands.command()
async def leader(self, ctx):
    desc = ""
    counter = 1
    async with aiosqlite.connect(self.DB) as db:   
        async with db.execute(
            "SELECT ID, sum(Punktestand) FROM Mitglieder GROUP BY ID ORDER BY Punktestand DESC LIMIT 35"

        ) as cursor: 
            async for ID, Punktestand in cursor:
                desc += f"{counter}. <@{ID}> ## {Punktestand} Punkt(e)\n"
                counter += 1

    embed = discord.Embed(color = 16705372)
    embed.add_field(name= "Leaderboard", value = desc, inline = False)
```

I use an SQL database in which points are distributed to the users. The output of the leader board should show the descending order after summing up the points. However, the order is not completely correct. One user appears in the middle despite being in the lead.

I have swapped order by and group by into the correct order. That should work so far.

Comment: You're not ordering by the sum of the points ...

Comment: You could do something like `"SELECT ID, SUM(Punktestand) as TotalPoints FROM Mitglieder GROUP BY ID ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC LIMIT 35"`. This way we sum the points and give it an alias that we can then use.

Answer (score 0):

As @snakecharmerb said in their comment: You are not ordering them by the sum of the points. With your function, you are just sorting the individual points (`Punktestand`) and nothing more.

To overcome this issue, you can implement a simple “intermediate step” in your function to sum it all:

```py
@commands.command()
async def leader(self, ctx):
    desc = ""
    counter = 1
    async with aiosqlite.connect(self.DB) as db:   
        async with db.execute(
            "SELECT ID, SUM(Punktestand) as TotalPoints FROM Mitglieder GROUP BY ID ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC LIMIT 35"
        ) as cursor: 
            async for ID, Punktestand in cursor:
                desc += f"{counter}. <@{ID}> ## {Punktestand} Punkt(e)\n"
                counter += 1

    embed = discord.Embed(color = 16705372)
    embed.add_field(name= "Leaderboard", value = desc, inline = False)
```

With `GROUP BY`, you are creating groups of rows based on the `ID` column.
The `SUM(Punktestand)` then sums the `Punktestand` values for each of these groups. To sum it all, I introduced `TotalPoints` as an "alias" that you can work with.